# React does not render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My react code does not seem to be working. I have the following html:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="example"></div>

        <form id="frm1" action="form_action.asp">
          First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
          Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br><br>
          <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Submit" class="btn-primary">
        </form>

        <script src="build/react.js"></script>
        <script src="build/react-dom.js"></script>
        <script type="text/babel" src="helloworld.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the following react code

helloworld.js:

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
      return(
         <div>
            <div className="commentText">Some Comment</div>
            <button onClick="">Edit</button>
            <button onClick="">Remove</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
});


function myFunction() {
        alert("hello world");
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Comment />,document.getElementById('example')
);
```

But it does neither spit out the comment in the example div, nor does it call the function for the input field. I suspect there is something wrong with my React setup in general, which is why I post both things here at the same time. However, the build folder and the referenced files do all exist.

Comment: Any errors in your browser console?

Comment: No, there are no errors, apart from the one related to the function which is not recognised, so there it gives me a 'Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined'. That's why I think it just does not recognise my react file (helloworld.js) at all.

Comment: You have missed a closing bracket (`)`) after `</div>` in your JSX (I'm surprised this didn't show as an error for you; it did for me).

Comment: thanks, I fixed that. but it's still not working. I am also surprised it didnt show up as an error, but that, again, would point to something being wrong with my setup, wouldnt it?

Comment: Are you trying to use Babel? It looks like `babel-browser` is [no longer supported](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/), so you'll have to transpile it using Webpack or some other build system and load it as normal JavaScript.

Comment: i'm not sure, i haven't thought about this much. could the problem be that I am trying to do this as part of an electron app? will i need to require a transpiler? what can i use if not babel? i'm sorry, i'm a beginner.

Answer (score 0):

It works, check [this link](http://codepen.io/Noctisdark/pen/dpqNEz?editors=1010) out.

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
   render: function(){
      return(
         <div>
            <div className="commentText">Some Comment</div>
            <button onClick="">Edit</button>
            <button onClick="">Remove</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
});


function myFunction() {
        alert("hello world");
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Comment />,document.getElementById('example')
);
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. it doesn't seem to work for me though. could the problem be that I am trying to do this as part of an electron app?

Comment: I don't think so. What transpiler are you using ? Any runtime errors ?

Answer (score 0):

Make use of webpack to transpile your code since babel-browser has been removed.**[see this](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/browser/)** Also react onClick event function can be defined in the react component itself in `helloworld.js` like

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
    handleClick: function() {
        alert("hello world");
   }
   render: function(){
      return(
         <div>
            <div className="commentText">Some Comment</div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick()}>Edit</button>
            <button onClick="">Remove</button>
         </div>
      );
   }
});

function myFunction() {
        alert("hello world");
}

ReactDOM.render(
   <Comment />,document.getElementById('example')
);
```

To set up webpack follow [this](https://www.codementor.io/reactjs/tutorial/beginner-guide-setup-reactjs-environment-npm-babel-6-webpack) link. Its easy to follow